# Does Orika support mapping from java.util.Set?

Tags: java, mapping, orika

I've used Orika before to map between many different objects and collections successfully, but I'm running into an issue when trying to map a java.util.Set to a series of fields. I'd prefer not changing the Set to a SortedSet or to a List if possible.

SourceObject has the property Set setField and DestinationObject has various String properties I'm trying to map to.

```
    mapperFactory.classMap(SourceObject.class, DestinationObject.class)
            .field("setField[0].propertyOne", "destinationOnePropertyOne")
            .field("setField[0].propertyTwo", "destinationOnePropertyTwo")
            .field("setField[1].propertyOne", "destinationTwoPropertyOne")
            .field("setField[1].propertyTwo", "destinationTwoPropertyTwo")
```

Trying this will throw the following exception when running a test:

```
Caused by: compile error: get(int) not found in java.util.Set
at javassist.compiler.TypeChecker.atMethodCallCore(TypeChecker.java:723)
at javassist.compiler.TypeChecker.atCallExpr(TypeChecker.java:688)
at javassist.compiler.JvstTypeChecker.atCallExpr(JvstTypeChecker.java:157)
at javassist.compiler.ast.CallExpr.accept(CallExpr.java:46)
at javassist.compiler.TypeChecker.atCastExpr(TypeChecker.java:547)
at javassist.compiler.JvstTypeChecker.atCastExpr(JvstTypeChecker.java:104)
at javassist.compiler.ast.CastExpr.accept(CastExpr.java:55)
at javassist.compiler.TypeChecker.booleanExpr(TypeChecker.java:515)
at javassist.compiler.TypeChecker.atBinExpr(TypeChecker.java:337)
at javassist.compiler.ast.BinExpr.accept(BinExpr.java:41)
at javassist.compiler.TypeChecker.booleanExpr(TypeChecker.java:527)
at javassist.compiler.TypeChecker.atBinExpr(TypeChecker.java:337)
at javassist.compiler.ast.BinExpr.accept(BinExpr.java:41)
at javassist.compiler.TypeChecker.booleanExpr(TypeChecker.java:523)
at javassist.compiler.TypeChecker.atExpr(TypeChecker.java:592)
at javassist.compiler.ast.Expr.accept(Expr.java:68)
at javassist.compiler.TypeChecker.booleanExpr(TypeChecker.java:527)
at javassist.compiler.TypeChecker.atBinExpr(TypeChecker.java:337)
at javassist.compiler.ast.BinExpr.accept(BinExpr.java:41)
at javassist.compiler.CodeGen.doTypeCheck(CodeGen.java:242)
at javassist.compiler.CodeGen.compileBooleanExpr(CodeGen.java:236)
at javassist.compiler.CodeGen.atIfStmnt(CodeGen.java:384)
at javassist.compiler.CodeGen.atStmnt(CodeGen.java:355)
at javassist.compiler.ast.Stmnt.accept(Stmnt.java:50)
at javassist.compiler.CodeGen.atStmnt(CodeGen.java:351)
at javassist.compiler.ast.Stmnt.accept(Stmnt.java:50)
at javassist.compiler.CodeGen.atMethodBody(CodeGen.java:292)
at javassist.compiler.CodeGen.atMethodDecl(CodeGen.java:274)
at javassist.compiler.ast.MethodDecl.accept(MethodDecl.java:44)
at javassist.compiler.Javac.compileMethod(Javac.java:169)
at javassist.compiler.Javac.compile(Javac.java:95)
at javassist.CtNewMethod.make(CtNewMethod.java:74)
... 79 more
```

It looks like Orika assumes there is a get(int) method on the collection, instead of trying to use an iterator. Is there a way to stick to using a Set, or will I need to do some refactoring to use another collection type?

Thanks for any thoughts!

Answer (score 1):

you're trying to access to set elements by an index, this is the issue.

If you want to keep your set you should not map elements by index or use List instead.

Comment: can you explain it with some example?

Comment: can we use collection Set for this?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, this is this solution that i use.

You must to change hbm from `<set>` tag to `<bag>` tag(in my case i changed only start tag, no other options and all worked as before), for example(Request.hbm):

```
<bag name="Solutions" table="S_SOLUTION" batch-size="20">
   <key>
      <column name="REQUEST_ID" not-null="true" />
    </key>
    <many-to-many entity-name="com.model.Solution">
        <column name="SOLUTION_ID" not-null="true" />
    </many-to-many>
</bag>
```

After you must to change in the bean file, the `Set` to `List`, for example(Request.java):

```
private List<Solution> Solutions = new ArrayList<Solution>();
public List<Solution> getSolutions() {
    return Solutions;
}
public void setSolutions(List<Solution> sSolutions) {
    Solutions = sSolutions;
}
```

Finally Orika can mapping the first element indexed with 0, example:

```
.field("solutionCreated","Solutions[0].creatorFullName")
.field("solutionText","Solutions[0].resolutionText")
```